# Alterar url das páginas com ajax e carregar em outro browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Estou com o seguinte problema, estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação web em java e gostaria de saber como faço para alterar a URL de uma página quando clico em um link do menu. Por exemplo:

Acesso um site www.exemplo.com.br esse é o link da principal e lá tem um outro link contato, quando eu clicar nele, gostaria que ficasse www.exemplo.com.br/contato. Além disso, queria poder copiar essa URL e abrir em um outro browser e ir direto para contato.

Um exemplo disso é o Gmail, quando clicamos para ler um email a url altera e se fizermos um copy past em outro browser vai direto para o email.

É possível fazer isso como ajax ? Se não for qual seria a melhor opção ?

Comment: Isso na verdade é uma mistura de History API e roteamento. Não tenho conhecimento se é possível fazer isso em Java. Ou você esta se referindo a Javascript?

Comment: Em javascript se é possível. Eu consigo carregar o conteúdo que eu quero em um div, mas queria fazer esse esquema da url como descrevi em cima ou senão qual a melhor forma pra se fazer isso ?

Comment: estás a usar Java ou JavaScript?

Comment: Neste caso, atualize sua questão. Java e Javascript são duas coisas completamente diferente, apesar do nome.

Comment: Estou utilizando javascript

Answer (score 3):

Como citou que está utilizando jQuery, recomendo o plugin da `History API`:

[History](http://plugins.jquery.com/history/)

Caso não deseje usar um plugin, recomendo este artigo que trata em detalhes como trabalhar com a API:

[history.pushState and jQuery](http://rosspenman.com/pushstate-jquery/)

O principal método desta API é o `history.pushState`. Ele pede 3 argumentos, embora o segundo não seja utilizado em alguns (todos?) browsers.

O primeiro argumento, é um objeto Javascript associado com o novo estado da aplicação. Este objeto é parâmetro do evento `popstate`, disparado quando um novo estado é navegado.

O segundo é o título do novo estado.

O terceiro é a URL do novo estado. Esta URL pode ser relativa ou absoluta e deve estar no mesmo domínio. O browser não irá executar uma chamada HTTP para este endereço, embora no caso da reinicialização do browser, ela pode ser chamada, e neste caso, sua aplicação deve tratar.

O evento `popstate`, ao contrário do que o nome sugere, não é disparado quando um estado é removido, e sim quando o estado do browser é alterado. Como dito, este evento possui um único parâmetro, que é o objeto associado com o estado.

Veja mais sobre esta API na documentação da Mozilla: [Manipulating the browser history](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history).

Como esta utilizando jQuery, recomendo utilizar um plugin, ao invés de gastar tempo reinventando a roda.

Comment: History API, com essa api eu consigo copiar a url e passar por exemplo para outra pessoa acessar, ou seja, seguindo aquele mesmo princípio do gmail ?

Comment: Sim, ela fornece os recursos necessários para isto. O próprio Gmail utiliza ela (é a defacto API para isto).